# Best way to complete this Perl regex one-liner

Tags: regex, perl, awk

I'm trying to use a Perl one-liner to munge some output from grepping svn diff, so I can automatically test the files.  We have a run_test.sh script that can take multiple PHP files prepended with 'Test" as its arguments.

So far I have the following which successfully prepends 'Test' to the file names

```
[gjempty@gjempty-rhel4 classes]$ svn diff | grep '(revision' | perl -wpl -e 's/(.*)\/(.*)$/$1\/Test$2/'
--- commerce/TestLCart.php      (revision 104387)
--- commerce/manufacturing/TestLRoutingData.php (revision 104387)
```

Now I'd just like to grab the file/path to pass it to our run_test.sh.  I can finish it off with awk as below, but am trying to improve my Perl/one-liner skills.  So how do I revise the perl one-liner to additionally extract only the file path?

```
 svn diff | grep '(revision' | perl -wpl -e 's/(.*)\/(.*)$/$1\/Test$2/' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs run_test.sh
```

Comment: Great answers all, I've been paying attention to them as they get revised.  Will things out tomorrow when I get back to work and will accept an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just wanting the file names, so `svn st` is what you want. Instead of getting large quantities of noise which could potentially contain `(revision` in it, and the main lines you want, you'll get it like this: `M       commerce/LCart.php`. Then you can just chop off `\S*` (any number of non-whitespace characters) followed by `\s*` (any number of whitespace characters), and take what's left. You could do the `\S*\s*` differently, but that's the simplest way to get all cases.

```
svn st | perl -wpl -e 's|\S*\s*(.*)/(.*)$|$1/Test$2|'
```

(Switched it after posting from using s/// to s||| so the / doesn't need to be escaped; good idea, Axeman.)

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the `grep` and the `awk` fairly easily.

```
svn diff | perl -wnl -e '/\(revision/ or next; m|(\S+)/(\S+)|; print "$1/Test$2";'
```

I changed the -p to -n.  -p means `while (<>) { <your code>; print $_; }`, and -n is the same but without the `print`, since the new version has an explicit `print` instead.

Rather than an `s///` substitution, I used an `m//` pattern match.  I changed the delimiter to `|` to avoid backslashing the slash (a cause of Leaning Toothpick Syndrome).  You can use almost any punctuation character you want.

`\S` is similar to `.` but matches only non-whitespace characters.  Your `.*`s in the pattern were actually matching the entire chunks of the line before and after the slash, but the new pattern only matches the pathname of the file.  Since the `+` is "greedy", the first one (`$1`) will get more string when there are multiple slashes in the pathname, the same as with your substitution pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Better version:

- No default print ( `-n`)
- Extract substring first
- Subst on that
- `print` value

  ```
  perl -wnl -e '($_)=m{---\s+(\S+)} and s|/([^/]+)$|/Test$1| and print "$_\n";'
  ```

You don't need `awk` now. And adding `'(revision` to the expression,

```
perl -wnl -e '($_)=m{---\s+(\S+)\s+\(revision} and s|/([^/]+)$|/Test$1| and print "$_\n";'
```

you don't need `grep` either.

But I have several subversion tools I created, and if all you want are the changed files `'svn st'` is better.

```
svn st | perl -wnle 'm/^[CM]\s+(\S+)/and$r=rindex($1,"/")+1and print substr($1,0,$r),"Test",substr($1,$r+1),"\n"'
```

This time I chose a `rindex` + `substr` method. Now, there's *no* regex backtracking.